# Jquery Autofocus second input

Tags: jquery, forms, autofocus

I found a way to focus next input in a form using jquery. But I have to add hidden inputs, after every input in my form. So this jquery function focuses on next hidden input. How can I pass through this hidden inputs?

```
$(function() {
    $('#fill1,#fill2,#fill3,#fill4,#fill5,#fill6').keyup(function(e) {
        if ($(this).val().length == $(this).attr('maxlength')) {
            $(this).next(':input').focus();
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can skip one by doubling next function like that:

```
$(this).next(':input').next(':input').focus();
```

[Here is jfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/fvtofpjs/1/)